# What is vmhgfs?

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a VMWare ESXi server with the RCLI appliance installed.  I was wondering if it was possible for the RCLI host to mount the filesystem of another guest.  I'm assuming there's some way for it to mount the vmfs (as I understand it, at least) where all the guest vmdk's (?) live.

I was looking for something like VMDKMounter.app on VMWare Fusion. So I went looking for what `mount.*` commands were available and I found `/sbin/mount.vmhgfs`.

What is vmhgfs?

Is it vmfs by a different name?

Will it let me mount vmdk's with an ext3 filesystem, assuming I could get the right mount point set up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the driver that allows the shared files feature of VMware Workstation and other products that use it.

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_running_shared_folders.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a lot of documentation on it, but it appears to be the vmware host/guest filesystem

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man9/vmhgfs.9.html